# Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are integers with $1 \le m \le 49$ and $n \ge 0$ s.t $m \mid n^{n+1} + 1$. What is the number of possible values of $m$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are integers with $1 \le m \le 49$ and $n \ge 0$ such that $m$ divides $n^{n+1} + 1$. What is the number of possible values of $m$?

If $m$ divides $n^{n+1} + 1$, then $n^{n+1} + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod m$ and so $n^{n+1}  \equiv -1 \pmod m$. This is equivalent to $n^{2n+2} \equiv 1 \pmod m$ and this holds if and only if $\text{ord}_m(n) \mid 2(n+1)$. This means that either $\text{ord}_m(n) \mid 2$ or $\text{ord}_m(n) \mid n+1$.

Now I tried to get to some casework from here first checking that when $\text{ord}_m(n) \mid 2$, then I should get that $\text{ord}_m(n) = 1$ or $\text{ord}_m(n) = 2$. If $\text{ord}_m(n) =1$, then $n \equiv 1 \pmod m$ so $n^{n+1} \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod m$ which is a contradiction. If $\text{ord}_m(n) = 2$, then $n^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod m$ so $n^{n+1} \equiv 2^{2+1} = 8 \pmod m$.

If $\text{ord}_m(n) = n+1$. But with this I'm at the congruence $n^{n+1} \equiv 1 \pmod m$ which is also not true as I had that $n^{n+1}  \equiv -1 \pmod m$ so what could be the problem here?

Comment: Saying that $n^{n+1}\equiv -1\pmod m$ is not *equivalent to* $n^{2n+2}\equiv 1 \pmod m$.  Consider $n=1$, for example.  Of course the former claim does imply the latter, but not the other way round.

Comment: Note too that if ord$_m(n)\,|\,(n+1)$ then we'd have $n^{n+1}\equiv 1 \pmod m$. But it is not true that you can then deduce that ord$_m(n)\,|\,2$.

Comment: I suggest:  go more slowly.  Try particular $m$.  It's easy for $m=1$ or $m=2$.  What about $3$?  $4$? $5$?  Note that if it fails for some particular $m$ then it fails for all multiples of that $m$.

Comment: $m=1$ will work for any integer $n \ge 0$ and $m =2$ will force $n$ to be odd. For $m=3$ I get that $n \equiv 2 \pmod 6$, for $m=4$ there is no integer solutions and lastly for $m=5$ I think I have that $n \equiv 4 \pmod 6$.

Comment: Be careful:  for $m=5$, say,  it is true that $n=4$ works, but $n=10$ does not (obviously).

Comment: I think you need to review basic modular arithmetic...you go very quickly and make lots of mistakes.  Take your time.  Check examples.    For this problem:  next do the case where $m=p$, an odd prime.  Look at examples, form a conjecture, test it and prove it.

Comment: The conjecture I got that is for $m$ odd I can take $n = m-1$ always so all odd $m$ should work for $1 \le m \le 49$. These clearly are not the only solutions since $m=2$ works too.

Comment: Ok, so prove the first part. Prove that $(m-1)^{m}\equiv -1\pmod m$ if $m$ is odd.  That's a big step (and it is not difficult).

Comment: If $n = m-1$ and $m$ is odd, then $n$ is even and $n+1$ is odd thus $n^{n+1}+1$ has a factor of $n+1$. I think this will prove that odd $m$ works always.

Comment: Yep, that'll do it.  Good, that's half the cases. And you have already shown that no multiple of $4$ will work.  So that just leaves one class of numbers to study.

Comment: You lost me. If all odd numbers will work and $m=4$ has no solutions then how am I left with only one class of numbers? Multiples of $2$?

Comment: No...some multiples of $2$ are divisible by $4$.

Comment: I should warn you, that the last case looks a bit subtle.  That is, it seems to work sometimes but not others.  There aren't a lot of cases here, so you can check them one by one if it comes down to that.

Comment: Multiples of $2$ that aren't multiples of $4$...?

Comment: Otherwise known as $2k$ for odd $k$.